# Create submenu item on Ribbon's Splitbutton

Tags: ribbon, delegate-control

I just want to know if it's possible to add submenu on a custom splitbutton by using a delegate control.

I know that the normal way is to use javascript function to create the submenu xml. But I was hoping to find a way to do that on the server side using a delegate control.

Regards,

Loïc